# Get image by id when preview an image before it is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I use below script for preview an image before it is uploaded.
I have a html like this:

```
<div>
    <img id="image" src="#">
</div>

<input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="readURL(this);">
```

and js like this:
(I use `jquery-2.0.0.min.js` )

```
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            var image = document.getElementById('image');
            console.log(image);

        }}
```

My problem is this: when I show image with this script before downloading I can't get image by `var image = document.getElementById('image');` and console log show this: `<img src="#" id="image">`. How I can get image that shown in it before uploading?

Comment: What data are you trying to get from the `img`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I select image with input I show this but I can't get it with `document.getElementById('image')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader()` `.readAsDataURL()` method returns results asynchronously. Include `var image = document.getElementById('image');console.log(image);` or `console.log($("#image")[0])` within `FileReader` `onload` event handler.

> The `FileReader` object lets web applications asynchronously read the
>   contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer,
>   using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

> `FileReader.readyState` Read only
>
> A number indicating the state of the `FileReader`. This is one of the following:
>
> EMPTY 0   No data has been loaded yet.
>
> LOADING   1   Data is currently being loaded.
>
> DONE  2   The entire read request has been completed.

```js
function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
       // do stuff when `.readAsDataURL()` completes
       var image = document.getElementById("image");
       image.src = e.target.result;
       console.log(image, e.target.result, reader.DONE);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="image" src="#" />
</div>

<input type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="readURL(this);">
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer :) . So How can I change my script?

Comment: What's the difference between this and the code in the question? Other than retrieving the `img` in the async callback it's logically the same.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan _"What's the difference between this and the code in the question?"_ As interpreted Question, here, OP was expecting to view `<img>` with `data URL` set as `src` of `img` by placing `console.log(image)` at next line following `onload` handler, which would not return expected result, as `.readAsDataURL()` returns results asynchronously. Adjusted placement of `console.log(image)` to callback to view `.result` of `FileReader`. Other than thay adjustment, you are correct, `js` at Question would remain same.

Comment: My original point was that the location of `var image = document.getElementById("image");` makes no difference as the `#image` element is present when the DOM loads, so the async callback makes no difference to that. The later edit you made which console.logs the `e.target.result` is what has solved the OPs problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, fair point. Considered placing that declaration outside of `onchange` event and `onload` event of `FileReader`, though not necessary to resolve actual Question.